# Adjusting tankless water heater temperature without factory controls?

Tags: water-heater

I have an older Noritz N-069M tankless water heater without a "remote control" or display. I *think* I am not using enough hot water to consistently keep the heater running while showering (water goes completely cold for a minute--never happens to my wife, who takes hotter showers). According to the installation manual online, the only way to adjust the set temperature is by temporarily plugging in a remote control.

Are there any other options? The only visible adjustments are for the gas manifold pressure. A similar model apparently has removable jumper connectors, but this one does not.

Comment: What are the allowed values for the inlet gas pressure to the heater, including adjustments?

Comment: According to the manual online it takes gas pressure from 4" to 10.5" W.C. This is a much wider allowable range than my Bosch 125B.

Answer (score 3):

If you cant find a remote try turning on the hot water in the sink to add additional hot water demand, This will waste some water but may not take much to keep you from getting the cold surprise.

Comment: Thinking about your answer made me realize that my low-volume showerhead is probably part of the problem! Too much heat, not enough water...Los Angeles in a nutshell.

Answer (score 1):

After 10 years of perfect operation this exact same problem suddenly appeared with our minimalist Bosch Aquastar 125B (no remote and about 117,000 BTU/h burner). It took a while to figure out the erratic operation was due to a new lower flow rate shower head I had installed first in one shower used mainly by my wife. I ended up removing the plastic disc flow restrictors in the handles of both of our two shower heads and the problem disappeared. The heater was shutting off due to flow dropping below the minumum.

Since we are responsible adults we can control the flow using the valve settings and don't use an outrageous amount of water. If you have users who can't or won't do this, you may be able to modify the flow restrictors or get new restrictors that allow say 2.0 gal/min flow rate.

For a while I had my wife run a small flow through the hot tap of the lavatory, but this seemed a waste and not reproducible so I fixed the head to allow a greater flow rate.

Background: When we got the tankless heater we had standard 2.5 gal/min shower heads and the tankless heater was not erratic. My wife later installed a 2.5 gal/min hand held head in the shower she uses. After some years of use it conked out and I replaced it with one with 1.4 gal/min flow restrictor and didn't realize that this would cause her erratic operation. I first took out the flow restrictor in her shower and drilled out the orifices a little, but still it would not keep the heater on reliably. I could have drilled more and tried again, but I just kept the restrictor out.

I tried to get new 2.0 gal/min restrictors to fit our shower heads, but couldn't find any locally that fit the small diameter of our very basic shower heads so I have removed the restrictors from both shower heads. These are $15 ea plastic heads with flexible hose so one can use in the hand. Great for washing feet and the dog.